# Compare Data In Excel Not Working

Tags: excel

I am working on an Excel Spread Sheet. Where one column has tiers and another column has ratings, so basically what I am trying to do is:

```
+---+-------+--------+
|   |   A   |   B    |
+---+-------+--------+
| 1 | Tiers | Rating |
| 2 | 1     | 1      |
| 3 | 1     | 1      |
| 4 | 3     | 1      |
| 5 | 3     | 2      |
| 6 | 2     | 3      |
| 7 | 1     | 3      |
| 8 | 1     | 3      |
+---+-------+--------+
```

I count each tiers

4 1's
1 2's

2 3's

so to get the maximum rating for each tier I multiply them by 3 so

4*3 = 12 for tier 1

1*3 = 3  for tier 2

2*3 = 6 for tier 3

now comparing that to the rating columns I add up all the values for tier one so 1+1+3+3 = 8

Now to get the percentage I take the 8/12 get 66.67%

so how can I achieve this in Excel? Please Help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to calculate the 8

```
=SUMIF(A2:A8,1,B2:B8)
```

and the following to calculate the 12

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A8,1)*3
```

Then you can just calculate the percentage using:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A8,1,B2:B8)/(COUNTIF(A2:A8,1)*3)
```

Comment: That Wont Work Because i need to add by according to tiers, i have to calculate the 8 based on 2 3's and 2 1's CountIF(takes range, and one criteria, that is what my issue is, i need to calculate the rating based on tiers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the formula you need.  The formula calculates for tier 1

```
=sumif(A2:A8,1,B2:B8)/(countif(A2:A8,1)* max(if(A2:A8=1,B2:B8)))
```

Broken down

Count the tier 1s.  Count the cells in column A if they contain a 1

```
=countif(A2:A8,1)
```

Get the maximum rating. Return the maximum value in column B if column A contains a 1

```
=max(if(A2:A8=1,B2:B8))
```

Sum the ratings for Tier 1. Sum if column A contains a 1

```
=sumif(A2:A8,1,B2:B8)
```

You can replace the 1 in the formula with a cell reference e.g D1 and enter 1 in D1.  Lock the ranges in the formula so that you can autofill across and put 2 in E1 and 3 in F1 etc.

```
=sumif($A$2:$A$8,D1,$B$2:$B$8)/(countif($A$2:$A$8,D1)* max(if($A$2:$A$8=D1,$B$2:$B$8)))
```